# Selection of technology implementation?

Tags: javascript, c#, sharepoint, spfx

I need to develop a small application integrated in sharepoint. I am using the 2019 version on on premise. The application consists of data entry, sql queries for loading data into the fields. I want to use the latest approaches for this purpose. I still have time, but I don’t know which way to go.

I looked at a lot of solutions without code, but as I understand it, I need to move in the direction of JS, at the same time I want to save it in sharepoint lists or where to store the entered data. But how can I get data from the external MSSQL database, use node.js or the web part, REST. I am very confused, help me please. I developed applications on C # windows form with ado.net, if I know the direction I will figure it out in JS.

Comment: Hi there, can you clarify what your application will do? Try to break it down in terms of Front-End & Back-End.
If I understood correctly you want a GUI that can fetch data from a Database and then update fields in Sharepoint. Is that correct?
If that's the case you may just need something like React for the Front-End, NodeJS to do operations on your data and interface with Sharepoint through their REST API.

Comment: Yes, that correct. Front-End this is the form in which the user enters data that fills in additional fields from the database (MSSQL). After that, the completed form is saved in the sharepoint list or somewhere else.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So following up with the comments, you could implement the following stack:

- [React](https://reactjs.org/) or [Vue](https://vuejs.org/): To implement a simple GUI to perform basic CRUD on you DB
- [NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/en/): To handle the data manipulation (if any) and push things to Sharepoint

Take a look at the very popular [MERV](https://codingthesmartway.com/the-mern-stack-tutorial-building-a-react-crud-application-from-start-to-finish-part-1/) stack for inspiration on the app structure. (MERV uses MongoDB, but the logic would be the same if you swap that bit for MySQL)

Using NodeJS you can leverage [Sharepoint REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-rest-endpoints) using the [available libraries](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sharepoint). Check out [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@mmismail109/use-sharepoint-restful-apis-with-node-js-9d62fbfab497) for details on the implementation.